# T-SQL How to leave two decimals without rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I am trying to leave number without rounding after data gets retrieved from .NET website.

For example, the number I get from the website is `10.7658234`

I would like to leave the number as `10.76` instead of rounding it to `10.77`.

Currently, the data type in SQL Server is `numeric(11,2)`.

How do I go about doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to truncate in SQL, `ROUND` has an optional third parameter that you can use to truncate instead of round:

```
SELECT ROUND(10.7658234,2,1)   -- 10.76
```

If you need to truncate *before* the SQL (e.g. if the number is being passed as a command parameter that has 2-digit precision), you'll need to change the code that sets the parameter to do the truncating.  Since you didn't specify *how* that's done here's how it's done in generic C# code:

```
double val = 10.7658234;
val = Math.Truncate(val * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: But currently, stored procedure just takes data into parameter: @Number(11,2) and update into a table in SQL. For example: UPDATE tblMisc SET tblMsic.nNumber = @Number where do I put Round(x, 2,1)?

Comment: @Kudohs then it will need to be changed in the application.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Kudohs I would also amend your question to specify that so it can be re-opened as a non-duplicate question.

Comment: Why @DStanley? If you'd assumed that the truncation was done in SQL rather than C# it could be done in the update statement... ROUND(@NUMBER,2,1)

Comment: @Ben The comment shows that the parameter type is `Numeric(11,2)` so it will be rounded to 2-digits before it ever gets to the UPDATE.  Therefore it needs to be changed in the app layer unless there's a way to change that behavior that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I tried using this number on application layer. 11806.206193333 using Math.Truncate(val * 100) / 100. But the outsome came out to be 11806.00.  What should I do?